# How can i find all network devices without Bonjour?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, network-programming

I writing a mac application and i need to discover other Macs/PCs/iPhones/iPads connected to the same WIFI network.

Bonjour seems to be the most reasonable choice, but it turned out that it has  problems on many types of routers (on mine for example, is not working as it blocks Bonjour services).

I just need to find iPs of devices, then i will try to connect to an application-specific port to determine if my process is running there.

What is the best approach to accomplish this task, without violating the App store Sandboxing?

Answer (score 0):

[ARP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258172/how-do-i-query-the-arp-table-on-iphone) was the first answer which came to my mind. Does your network-setup allows this?