# Find devices in network iOS

Tags: ios, networking, find

I need to find all devices registered in network, they IP and MAC address (like Fing app). I try to use bonjour, but it detect only published services, not devices. I spend a lot of time to find out how to do it, but there no results. Please help me!

Comment: What does "registered in network" mean?

Comment: devices that used the same wifi network that my phone.

Comment: Hi Yuriy..Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I too am struggling with this question. The best answers I have found on the SO community are here.

1. Use apples SimplePing open source Code [found here] (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/simpleping/introduction/intro.html)
   This will allow you to ping ip addresses and load the arp table.
2. Use this SO code to convert the ips to mac addresses by looking in the Arp table [ip2mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258172/how-do-i-query-the-arp-table-on-iphone)
3. Make sure to include the headers from /usr/include/netinet (just search your machine for the appropriate .h files found at the ip2mac post)