# NSNetServiceBrowser to find any device on network

Tags: ios, networking, nsnetservicebrowser

As per the title:

I am wondering how IOS is able to find devices on the network that are non-bonjour. Specifically I need to find a control device that will in the future have the appropriate Bonjour announce code but there are tons of these devices already out in consumers hands and firmware updates are not an option.

How then can I use Bonjour or NSNetServiceBrowser or some other library that is compatible with   the apple store to discover on the network older devices?

IE - in android I pinged all available IPs on the network and read the arp table for the proprietary mac prefix. This is, as I understand, not allowed on the mac store standards as I'd be using a library that is "not public"

I'm quite new to IOS programing and would Like any advice or help. Thanks?

Comment: You can use 3rd party libraries. You just can't use (directly or indirectly) private Apple APIs.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. Do you have any recommendations for where to look? I'm quite new to this IOS world. :)

Comment: You said you had a library but couldn't use it since it was "private". I simply pointed out that is probably isn't "private". I have no idea what the library is nor do I know. Also note that questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Oops Sorry. The library in question is a part of the private mac APIs library which has the arp functionality written into it. Others who have posted similar quandaries and used such libraries have been denied access to the apple store. [See this code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bootp/bootp-133.8/bootplib/arp.c)

Comment: OK, yes. If it's a private Apple API then you can't use it. I thought you meant some 3rd party library you found.